# Como obter o tempo do sistema operacional em nanosegundos ou milisegundos utilizando o Qt Creator?

Tags: c, c++, qt, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Como posso obter o tempo do sistema em nanosegundos ou milisegundos em `C++` utilizando o `Qt Creator`?

Por exemplo, em `Java` uso:

```
long tempoInicial = System.nanoTime();
treinaRNAEpocas(10000);
long tempoFinal = System.nanoTime();
long tempoDecorridoNs = tempoInicial - tempoFinal;
```

ou mesmo:

```
long tempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
treinaRNAEpocas(10000);
long tempoFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();
long tempoDecorridoMs = tempoInicial - tempoFinal;
```

Comment: Estou utilizando Ubuntu.

Comment: Realmente precisa para todas essas formas? Se eu não dormir eu posso tentar colocar alguma delas.

Comment: Acho que exagerei, haha. Pode ser só em C++ (com ou sem Qt, fica a escolha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Usando a Qt

Segue um exemplo adaptado da própria **[documentação da Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtime.html)**:

```
QTime t;
t.start(); // Aqui inicializamos a contagem

// seu código
treinaRNAEpocas(10000);

//resultado da medida
qDebug( "Tempo decorrido: %d milissegundos", t.elapsed() );
```

Notar que o [QTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtime.html) é adequado para medidas de até 24 horas, e como ele faz uso do relógio do sistema, está limitado a testes que não coincidam com ajustes do relógio (manualmente ou de maneira automática).

A precisão depende bastante do OS.

## C++ em Linux

Você pode usar o `clock_gettime()`, que tem boa precisão, conforme o exemplo retirado **[deste blog](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/)**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end);

int main() {
    timespec time1, time2;
    int temp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
    // seu código vai aqui /////////////////
    treinaRNAEpocas(10000);
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
    cout<<diff(time1,time2).tv_sec<<":"<<diff(time1,time2).tv_nsec<<endl;
    return 0;
}

timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end) {
    timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

## e para Windows

Esta solução foi encontrada **[nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739265/916193)** do "SOzão".

```
#include <windows.h>

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter() {
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";
    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}

double GetCounter() {
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}

int main() {
    StartCounter();
    // seu código vai aqui /////////////////
    treinaRNAEpocas(10000);
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    cout << GetCounter() <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, isto vai servir. Quero medir o tempo de treinamento de uma rede neural. :)

Comment: @Avelino, Para medir tempos de treino de redes neuronais, não precisas de nanosegundos! (basta um relogio de cozinha:)

Comment: @JJoao eu sei. Mas resolvi perguntar a título de curiosidade (posso precisar disto algum dia) e estou medindo o tempo para cada neurônio também.

Comment: @Avelino, Claro, eu entendi, e estudar estes assuntos é sempre relevante e com suspresas!

Answer (score 1):

Só um complemento (na realidade isto é um comentário formatado):

a função `clock_gettime()` tem uma grande precisão.
Embora no caso presente provavelmente não seja preciso sequer microsegundos (a ultima rede neuronal com que andei metido, estava a levar 3 dias a treinar), em relação à precisão do `clock_gettime` queria só lembrar que existe associado a esta função uma outra:

```
clock_getres(...)
```

que permite obter a precisão / resolução do valor retornado por `clock_gettime()`.

A resolução / precisão dos clocks, depende da implementação (compromisso entre consumo
e precisão)