# Como posso obter o tempo de carregamento e execução de um programa?

Tags: runtime

Como posso obter o tempo de carregamento e execução de um programa?

Desejo saber o tempo de carregamento e execução de um programa, desde o *momentum* em que o usuário dá ordem para executá-lo e o sistema operacional faz a alocação na memória RAM, até o momento em que o processo é encerrado.

Comment: Se a comunidade achar que é uma duplicada [desta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55086/como-obter-o-tempo-do-sistema-operacional-em-nanosegundos-e-milisegundos-com-qt), podem encerrar. Mas compreendo que são duas perguntas distintas. Principalmente o cálculo do tempo de execução de um programa, já que se o próprio programa em questão for responsável por calcular o seu próprio tempo de execução, ele irá influenciar no resultado final, deixando o resultado impreciso.

Comment: Você quer saber da complexidade do algoritmo ou o tempo efetivo que o programa demora? A pergunta parece estar genérica demais. Eu não sei o que responder.

Comment: Perdão, mas não consigo fazer a distinção entre os dois termos: "Complexidade de algoritmo" e "tempo efetivo". :S

Comment: Complexidade de algoritmo é apenas a função em si, e o tempo efetivo seria o tempo total do programa (incluindo a criação do processo, alocação na memória RAM, etc.)?

Comment: Achei que você sabia, afinal você usou uma *tag* com o termo. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101. Tempo efetivo é o tempo medido.

Comment: Não não, ainda estou estudando... (Obrigado pelo link). Quero medir o tempo efetivo, o tempo total do programa.

Comment: Como você mesmo mencionou, entendo que é duplicata desta, também sua: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55087/ - Sei que você está perguntando por dois enfoques diferentes, mas no fim a resposta é a mesma: você pega o tempo do sistema no início e no fim do programa, e calcula a diferença. É desprezível a captura deste tempo, desde que você faça apenas uma vez no começo e uma no fim (sem colocar código extra dentro de loops).

Comment: Encontrei o que precisava [aqui](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~lotufo/cursos/EA877/sistemas-operacionais/exemplos/tempo.c). Imagine um programa grande, que demora para ser carregado na memória. O tempo do carregamento deixará de ser desprezível. Fui infeliz na minha pergunta, deveria ter perguntado o tempo do processo. Desculpem a confusão. O programa que coloquei na resposta serve para o que preciso. Sintam-se livres para modificar minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seguinte código faz o que você precisa:

```
/*
Compilacao: gcc tempo.c -o tempo

Execucao: tempo <comando>
      onde <comando> pode ser ls por exemplo

Sugestao de Modificacoes:
1. Retire a chamada wait(NULL) e observe o comportamento
2. Faca com que cada processo imprima o seu pid
   o pid 'e obtido chamando-se getpid()
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int pid;
  struct timeval tv1, tv2;
  double t1, t2;

  if(argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Uso: tempo algum_comando\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  pid = fork();                                /* fork */
  if(pid == 0) {
    printf("\nProcesso filho vai executar %s agora.\n",argv[1]);
    gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);   /* processo pai continua ... */
    t1 = (double)(tv1.tv_sec) + (double)(tv1.tv_usec)/ 1000000.00;
    system(argv[1]);             /* processo filho executa comando */
    gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
    t2 = (double)(tv2.tv_sec) + (double)(tv2.tv_usec)/ 1000000.00;
    printf("\nExecucao de %s terminou agora.\n",argv[1]);
    printf("\nO tempo de execucao de %s por filho foi: %lf\n", 
    argv[1], (t2 - t1));
  }
  else{  
    gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);   /* processo pai continua ... */
    t1 = (double)(tv1.tv_sec) + (double)(tv1.tv_usec)/ 1000000.00;
    /*    wait(NULL); */            /* sincroniza com o termino do filho */
    gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
    t2 = (double)(tv2.tv_sec) + (double)(tv2.tv_usec)/ 1000000.00;
    printf("\nO tempo de execucao de processo pai foi: %lf\n",(t2 - t1));
  }
}
```

Baseado no exemplo: http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~lotufo/cursos/EA877/sistemas-operacionais/exemplos/tempo.c

Comment: Esse código é complicado para o que você perguntou por pelo menos dois motivos: Primeiro, que fork() não é multiplataforma, e segundo que esta técnica vai contabilizar não apenas o tempo de execução, mas a carga do HD e todas as alocações e liberaçoes de memória e recursos no início e no fim do programa (que pode ser ou não o que você quer, seria o caso de especificar na pergunta). Ainda acredito que a outra pergunta vá dar alguma coisa mais concreta para o que você precisa.

Comment: Era bem o que eu precisava, ele só termina de contabilizar o tempo quando o programa é encerrado. Acho que modifiquei minha pergunta para dar a entender isto, peço desculpas pela confusão. Mas sinta-se livre para modificar minha pergunta.

Comment: Não há porque pedir desculpas, nem creio que seja o caso de mexer na pergunta. Se for essa a solução, você pode procurar o [`timeit.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) para Windows, ou usar o `Measure-Command` do Powershell, e no Linux temos o `time`, que já faz esta medição. Não seria nem um problema de programação, por isso acho mais promissora a outra pergunta.